# Downgrade the Angular CLI to a specific version - error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to downgrade the Angular CLI version from 14 to 12.2.16 and every time I try I get the same problem. Even if I specify which version I want the last version gets installed.

This is what I have currently:
[image]

I want Angular CLI to go to version 12.2.16 as the Angular version.

I did the following steps but they did not help:

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli@12.2.16`
4. `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.16 --force`

Answer (score 0):

Install angular 12 in a new project, then compare the `package.json` of that new project with your `package.json` and make the `@angular` versions sync up, then check the [upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/) and see where changes need to be made on the code.

Then do the commands in order,

1. delete package-lock.json and node_modules
2. npm install

This will bring you closer to the downgrade completion! But other packages might trigger legacy peer dependency errors, in that scenario, in the dummy project you create install the same package, then use that version in your project!

Comment: @Alex97 does this answer solve your issue?